# Upgrade to 18.04 using Ubuntu wiki

Tags: upgrade

I would like to try MythTV but first it seems that I ought to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. Using Ubuntu wiki BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes".  The first step says that I should open the "Software & Updates" Setting in System Setting but I can find no "Software & Updates" in system Settings.  Is there a way around this.  There seem to be many sources for this information, all a little different.  I assumed the Ubuntu wiki would be the best curated (close to the source).  Is this so?  Can anyone recommend a more reliable way to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

To open "Software & Updates" run on terminal:

`software-properties-gtk`

[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_or_17.10) is good.

Answer (score 0):

Install package `update-manager-core` if it is not already. Perform full upgrade (`apt update && apt upgrade && apt dist-upgrade`).

Then, run in a terminal `sudo do-release-upgrade`. This is a CLI way to upgrade Ubuntu releases.

For a GUI version you can use the command `update-manager`, but I’m not sure which package this is found in. But supposedly this should be part of your existing installation.

Supposedly the upgrade can be around 1.5GB so try to have good internet or a lot of time when you do this.

See this similar question: 
[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: The upgrade started but stopped with the following comment.  Where should I go from here?                                              "Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal."

Comment: Maybe you have PPAs that are causing issues, try disabling them, downgrade packages to their regular versions and try again.